# Search for a particular word in a txt file in python

Tags: python, file, python-3.x, file-io

Say I had a txt file which contains the following information:

```
Name, Score

bob, 3
jack, 8
ben, 4
```

How can I get python to find "bob", and copy bob's whole line to a variable?

Answer (score 1):

It is often handy to read a table into a [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_table.html) data frame and perform your query using `pandas`. For example:

```
import pandas as pd

# The text file
txt_file = r'C:\path\to\your\txtfile.txt'

# Read the .txt file into a pandas dataframe
df = pd.read_table(txt_file, sep = ",")

# Isolate the row based on your query
row = df.loc[df['Name'] == 'ben']
```

---

```
>>> row
  Name   Score
2  ben       4
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `csv` module instead of custom acrobatics.

```
import csv
with open(csvfile) as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    for row in reader:
        if row['Name'] == 'bob':
            got = row
            break
>>> got
>>> {' Score': ' 3', 'Name': 'bob'}
```

You should wrap it in a function.

Answer (score -1):

Following code will open a file in reading mode, read all lines and if it finds `bob` in any line, it will print the whole line:

```
with open('path_to_your_text_file', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        if "bob" in line:
            print line
```